# how EC Public key is generated from the private key effectively

Tags: bitcoin-core, ethereum

if my private key is 123456789123456789, doesn't that mean I have to dot G point that many times to generate my pubkey? there must be a shortcut to generate pubkey, otherwise the time complicity of generating the pubkey is the same compare to brutal force from trying from 1 to k? Am I missing anything here?

[image]

according to the article here: https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/a-relatively-easy-to-understand-primer-on-elliptic-curve-cryptography/

it looks like generating pubkey from a random generated private key(which could be a 32 bytes BigInteger) requires to dot many times = integer value of the private key. which is impossible considering the key size for the private key is 2^256(32 bytes key space).

Comment: This sounds exactly like what someone with a private key of 123436789123456789 would say...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of more efficient algorithms to compute the multiplication than just the naive method described. A simple one is double-and-add where the point is repeatedly doubled and then added with previous doublings in order to calculate the final public key. There are a number of more complicated methods which are more efficient.

You can read about these on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication).

Comment: that's exactly what I was hoping for. thank you.